# Iterating arrays with elements containing spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

Given an array of two elements,

```
array=("foo bar" baz)
```

Using a `for..in` loop with the "normal" syntax yields **three** iterations (elements of the array are expanded).

```
for element in ${array[@]}
do echo $element
done
```

*Output:*

```
foo
bar
baz
```

While a `for..in` loop with the "index" syntax works as intended (elements are not expanded).

```
for i in ${!array[@]}
do echo ${array[i]}
done
```

*Output:*

```
foo bar
baz
```

Is there any way to use the first syntax construct as I intend (i.e. to get the same results as those I get using the second construct)?

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes make the difference, so you need to update your code to the following:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
   echo $element
done
```

Note

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
               ^           ^
```

instead of

```
for element in ${array[@]}
```

#### Test

```
$ array=("foo bar" baz)
$ for element in "${array[@]}"; do echo $element; done
foo bar
baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"; do 
  echo "${element}"
done
```

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS) would tell:

> IFS is a list of characters that separate fields; used when the shell
>   splits words as part of expansion.

Doing:

```
IFS=$''
for element in ${array[@]}; do 
  echo "${element}"
done
```

would also give the expected result.

Comment: Just curious, is `$''` a typo?  (Sorry by the way, I think fedorqui pulled the trigger a little faster ;))

Comment: @user2266481 No, it's not a *typo*.  It resets `IFS` so that word splitting would not be performed when whitespaces are encountered.

Comment: Okay, I was actually wondering about the dollar sign, which I've never used to set IFS or to prefix an empty string.  Things seem to work out fine without it, could you expand a little bit on it?

Comment: @user2266481 Using `$''` makes bash interpret escape sequences within `''`.  So you could conveniently say things like `$'\t\n'` ...